# Two screens with the same dimensions but different resolutions

Tags: android, resolution, density-independent-pixel

Assume we have two android devices with the same screen dimensions, but with different resolutions. Is the following true or not: if dp unit is used to set the sizes of all views, then both screens will display the same amount of contents and the only difference will be the crispness of the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the screens are the same physical dimension but have a differing dpi and you've used the dp (Density-independent pixel) then they should be the same as this is the point of the dp unit.

This [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) shows more about the handling of screen sizes and derivation of dp values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, dp (or dip) means density independent pixel.  [Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence)

So it's independent of the pixel density of the device.